# initialising field seperators on condition in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I know that initialising FS in BEGIN is the correct practice but what if i need different field seperators for different lines(lines containing a particular pattern)? eg: my awk script is

```
{if($0 ~ /.*youtube.*/){FS="=";print $2}}
```

This code is not processing the first line.How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`.  Eks get the middle date from third field `green`

```
echo "on,cat ,blue|green|red,more" | awk -F, '{split($3,a,"|");print a[2]}'
green
```

And you `BEGIN` block is not only where you can set the Field Separator:

```
echo "on,two,three" | awk -F, '{print $2}'
echo "on,two,three" | awk '{print $2}' FS=,
echo "on,two,three" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print $2}'
echo "on,two,three" | awk -v FS=, '{print $2}'
```

All these will print `two`

But they may have some different impact in when they can be used.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print FS}'
,
```

and this does not work and gives no output.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print FS}' FS=,
```

---

Back to your problem:

This:

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /.*youtube.*/){FS="=";print $2}}' file
```

should be:

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /.*youtube.*/){split($0,a,"=");print a[2]}}' file
```

You do not need to test for any characters before and after regex, so:

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /youtube/){split($0,a,"=");print a[2]}}' file
```

And this could even more be simplified:

```
awk '/youtube/ {split($0,a,"=");print a[2]}' file
```

---

If data is like this:

```
cat file
youtube=thisisyoutube1 //starts here
youtube=thisisyoutube2
youtube=thisisyoutube3
youtube=thisisyoutube4
yautube=thisisnottobeprinted
```

Then do like this:

```
awk -F= '/youtube/ {split($2,a," ");print a[1]}' file
thisisyoutube1
thisisyoutube2
thisisyoutube3
thisisyoutube4
```

Comment: input is

youtube=thisisyoutube1  //starts here
youtube=thisisyoutube2
youtube=thisisyoutube3
youtube=thisisyoutube4
yautube=thisisnottobeprinted

my output is
                //a new line
thisisyoutube2
thisisyoutube3
thisisyoutube4
thisisnottobeprinted

Comment: @sairamkolla Not possible read this in your comment, update your original post and use code tags  `{}` around code.  Post input data and what to get out from it.

Comment: All good but the 3rd arg for split() is a regexp (actually a field separator, which is a type of regexp), not a string, so use regexp delimiters (i.e.`split($0,a,/=/)` instead of `split($0,a,"=")`) so awk doesn't have to convert that arg from a string to a regexp. It matters for some contents of that argument so it's a good habit to get into to avoid surprises.